# My Chartjs is not updating after setstate full code attached Reactjs Update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

Chartjs is not showing my changes after updating the datasets value.
I have the slider controller from material ui.
I am using import update from 'immutability-helper'; to update the state.

```
<PrettoSlider valueLabelDisplay="auto" aria-label="pretto slider" defaultValue={20} onChange={handleChange}/>
```

my chart looks like this.

```
const RadarChart = () => {
const data = {
  datasets: [
    {
      data: [1, 3, 7, 3, 4, 6],
    },
  ],
};
  const [update, setUpdate] = useState(data.datasets[0].data[2]);
  // Initialized a hook to hold the reference to the title div.
  const titleRef = useRef();

  const handleChange = (e, v) => {
    // Imutable Update .. nested Object .. really hard to this manually. 
    const newDate = update(dataState,{
      datasets: {
        data: {$set: v}
      }
    } )
    setDataState(newDate)
    titleRef.current.render();
    titleRef.current.update();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <CustomizedSlider handleChange={handleChange} />
      <Radar ref={titleRef} data={data} />
    </>
  );
};
```

The slider works and I get the correct values in my handleChange method, so my problem relies with updating the state of the chart itself.

Comment: Try cloning the data instead of sending a reference to an object to `useState`

Comment: Can you post an example code. Thanks @Dominik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[In ReactJS you need to use the `useState()` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) for any data (state) you want to update. Something like this:

```
  const RadarChart = () => {
  const data = {
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [1, 3, 7, 3, 4, 6],
      },
    ],
  }
  const [dataState, setDataState] = useState(data)
  const [update, setUpdate] = useState(data.datasets[0].data[2]);    // <-- Is this necessary? You don't seem to be using it.
  
  const titleRef = useRef();

  const handleChange = (e, v) => {
      // create a copy of the array:
      let newArr = [...dataState.datasets[0].data];
      newArr[2] = v;
      // set state to updated array:
      setDataState(previous => ({
          ...previous,
          datasets: [{data: newArr}]
      }))
      setUpdate(v);     // best to use v here as dataState may not be finished updating, but again, don't know if necessary.
  };

  useEffect(()=>{
    if (titleRef.current) {  
      titleRef.current.render()
      titleRef.current.update()
    }
  }, [dataState])    // moved this update into a `React.useEffect` block, to make sure `dataState` has updated when they are triggered.

  return (
    <>
      <CustomizedSlider handleChange={handleChange} />
      <Radar ref={titleRef} data={dataState} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Another thing you can do is use state for one of the elements of the array, which saves a few lines of code, as the state is an integer and not an object. You would do it like this:

```
  const RadarChart = () => {
  const [variableState, setVariableState] = useState(7);
  const data = {
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [1, 3, variableState, 3, 4, 6]
      },
    ],
  };
  
  const titleRef = useRef();

  const handleChange = (e, v) => {
      setVariableState(v);
  };

  useEffect(()=>{
    if (titleRef.current) {  
      titleRef.current.render()
      titleRef.current.update()
    }
  }, [variableState])

  return (
    <>
      <CustomizedSlider handleChange={handleChange} />
      <Radar ref={titleRef} data={data} />
    </>
  );
};
```

This might be trickier depending on how you are getting the data though.

**Update to question regarding [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper#readme)**

At a glance, the problem with immutability-helper, it looks like you are trying to set the value of the array itself to `v` (`v` being just a single number). You should be using `data` instead of `dataState` in the update method. Also it looks like a different object you are creating. `data.datasets` was an array before and it is an object in your update. Not exactly sure why you wouldn't just use the `setDataState` function in the same ways as above, seems less complicated, and doesn't require external libraries.

I literally just read the docs myself but you could try something similar to above:

```
let newArr = [...data.datasets[0].data];
newArr[2] = v;
const newData = update(data,{
      datasets: {$set: [{data: newArr}]}});
setDataState(newData);
```

Comment: I am getting TypeError: dataState.datasets[0] is not iterable @nihilok

Comment: Sorry I was on my phone before and missed a `.data` ...I have now edited the answer in 2 places.

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked. , can you please update your answer with using the update from 'immutability-helper'; to update the state. @nihilok

Comment: You can do what I would have to do and [read the readme](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper#readme)

Comment: I have accepted your answer because it worked for me, I am also trying to do that using the immutable helper I update my question, for some reason what I have doesn't work, if you got the timeplease have a look, you might be able to spot my mistake. @nihilok

Comment: There's a couple of things I can see that don't look right. Updated the answer.

Comment: I added a possible solution